# Equivalence Principle Frame Dragging

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle, kerr-metric, frame-dragging

Why do metric equations of a rotating body (like Kerr Metric for black holes or EFE solution for rotating bodies) contain a dt dphi term, leading to rotational frame dragging effects? Please don't just say it's just the EFE solution, I want a more intuitive explanation. We can explain both gravitational time dilation and space expansion of the Schwartzchild Metric using equivalence principle - not the exact amount but why it happens. I prefer a similar intuitive explanation for frame dragging of the rotating bodies.